# LLVM - How to get the result variable of an instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm a beginner with LLVM, and I have a simple problem, but I can't find the solution in the documentation.

I'm doing a function pass that computes on instructions, and for this I need all 'data' from the instruction, I mean the operator, all operands, and the result.

My problem is, I can't get the result variable. For example, for the instruction:

```
%add1 = add nsw i32 %x, %y
```

I can have *x* and *y* name and variable, I can have the opCode, I can have *add1* name, but, I can not have *add1* variable.

I read all functions from the [Instruction](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html) page of the documentation, and I can't find anything who looks like what I'm looking for.

So what is the proper API that can solve my problem?

Comment: Just a side note: you'd better not use the term "variable" for LLVM IR,  since `%add1` *is* an **Instruction**, and it **Uses** *%x* and *%y* (operands), which can be any subclass instances of **Value**. *variable* is officially only used for [GlobalVariable](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Instruction` inherits from `Value` and thus has method `getName()` which solves your problem.
But remember that instruction can be unnamed (such as `%0`) and `getName` probably won't return anything useful in that case

Comment: As I told, I knew that I can get the 'name' of the instruction, so you didn't answer my question. But I didn't pay attention to the fact that    Instruction inherits from    Value, so I can use an    Instruction as a    Value, and this answers my question ! So you solve my problem, thanks ;)

Comment: I didn't get how you got the add1 variable using the fact that the Instruction is a Value.